# Cursor inside loop is returning only last record

Tags: mysql, oracle

I am trying to get IDs from table1 and select data from table2 based on retrieved IDs. So I have opened a cursor1 to retrieve those IDs then I tried to loop over it and fill cursor2 with details of table2. When debugging I realized that cursor1 is filled correctly, looping is working perfectly but only the last record is returned. Below is my oracle procedure:

```
PROCEDURE TEST_LIST(P_ITEM_ID    NUMBER,                                
                    P_REFCUR     OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS  

  BEGIN

      DECLARE CURSOR  V_REFCUR  is
              SELECT T.ID
              FROM MY_TABLE_NAME T
              WHERE T.ITEM_ID = P_ITEM_ID;  

      BEGIN

        FOR V IN V_REFCUR LOOP
          IF V.ID IS NOT NULL THEN
            OPEN P_REFCUR FOR  
              SELECT G.*                             
              FROM MY_SECOND_TABLE G
              WHERE G.ID = V.ID
              ORDER BY G.TABLE_DATE;
          END IF;
        END LOOP;
      END;

  END TEST_LIST;
```

How can I return the whole list? I am new to SQL , I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the first cursor. Do the simple join between first and second table.

```
PROCEDURE TEST_LIST(P_ITEM_ID    NUMBER,                                
                    P_REFCUR     OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS  

  BEGIN
            OPEN P_REFCUR FOR  
              SELECT G.*                             
              FROM MY_SECOND_TABLE G
              join MY_TABLE_NAME T
              on G.ID = T.ID
              WHERE T.ITEM_ID = P_ITEM_ID
              ORDER BY G.TABLE_DATE;

   END;

  END TEST_LIST;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply it is working perfectly now